# Setting up HTTP authentication in a dev box

Tags: http, authentication, nginx

The situation I have is that I have a dev box full of different applications like a minecraft server, a couchdb server, and a basic wordpress blog behind nginx, which handles forwarding.

Now they all have their own way of handling logins, but what i'd like to set up is somekind of authentication proxy.

In a sense, intercept all the HTTP requests coming to the server and check if they are authenticated, if not return a login page, if they are let the request through to wordpress or couchdb. I could have a list of users in the server to let my friends login with 1 log.

I've tried googling with many different key words but haven't found out how this could be done with for example NGINX? Im a bit of a newbie when it comes to networking please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a rough example to do HTTP auth in nginx and then proxy the connection to the original source:

```
location /couchdb {
    auth_basic "Restricted";
    auth_basic_user_file htpasswd;
    rewrite /couchdb/(.*) /$1 break; # Optional, depends on what you're proxying to
    proxy_pass http://localhost:5984;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

The above is from the [couchdb docs](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Nginx_As_a_Reverse_Proxy), but the general idea is applicable to any HTTP-based app you want to protect.  You'd need to repeat this config block for every distinct app.

Note the rewrite in the above setup lets you work with apps that don't expect to live anywhere but the URL root.  It is not required.

Also note that if you want to have a single page where users log in and then have that login be shared across all your apps, that is much more complicated.  That is commonly referred to as `Single Sign On` and requires a specific configuration for each app that you'd intend to integrate.

Comment: Thanks for this! It's difficult to google the stuff without knowing too much of it. I should try to formulate my question better, i really don't need to have a sigle sign on, so that the users get signed into the other apps, just that the access to them is behind 1 login page. For example if I have a static HTML file type of a web page served from couchdb, but I want to restrict access to just the people who have access to my server through NGINX.

Comment: Yup, that's what I figured you really wanted, hence the HTTP auth solution.  Try it and if you're happy, give a +1 and accept the answer.

Comment: Something that could also work and being much nicer than the ugly HTTP auth could be a simple django page(that's living in the server also, don't ask.) that provides oauth login. Then set up nginx to forward to this page when not authorized. Then you login with a proper oauth and you get access to the rest of the server.

Comment: As a bit more robust user handling would be great than basic HTTP auth.

Comment: Sure, but then all your apps have to handle oauth tokens.  Can they?  Do your friends really care if the login page is ugly?  :)

Comment: Don't think they'll mind but it's a nice challenge. Do the applications really need to handle the tokens, isn't it enough for NGINX to handle the token?

Comment: It depends how you define success.  If you want your user to present a login/pass and then *not again when they access the underlying app*, then you need app-level oauth support, and hence my comment about `SSO`.  If you don't care about that then sure, have fun, but know that what you're doing is functionally equivalent to HTTP auth.  This link may be helpful: http://seatgeek.com/blog/dev/oauth-support-for-nginx-with-lua